# Magento: Send a mail directly to my supplier when payment is set to be received

Tags: email, magento, payment

I'd like to send an automatic email to my supplier, when the order is checked as payed. I've a external supplier that start to produce when i tell him, so when the payment is received, I can confirm to him the production. I'd like to automate this process and I like to use a similar confirmation order email, but adding a custom attribute instead of the sku.
Thank you!

--- EDIT ---
I'm reached my goal inserting those lines, but I've still some problem in the Observer line 24 at $result line, there's an error for one ",".
config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
<modules>
    <Electricjesus_Notifyowner>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Electricjesus_Notifyowner>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <notifyowner>
            <class>Electricjesus_Notifyowner_Model</class>
        </notifyowner>
    </models>          
    <events>
            <sales_order_payment_pay>
                <observers>
                    <notifyOwnerEvent>
                            <class>notifyowner/observer</class>
                            <method>notifyOwnerEvent</method>
                    </notifyOwnerEvent>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_payment_pay >     
    </events>
 </global>
```

Electricjesus_Notifyowner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Electricjesus_Notifyowner>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Electricjesus_Notifyowner >
</modules>
```

and Observer.php with the error

```
    // parameters you can get from the $observer parameter:
    // array(’payment’ ? $this, ‘invoice’ ? $invoice)

    $payment = $observer->getPayment();
    $invoice = $observer->getInvoice();

    // derivative data
    $order = $invoice->getOrder(); // Mage_Sales_Model_Order

    $ownerEmail = 'test@gmail.com';

    $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
        ->loadDefault('order_new');
    $emailTemplate
        ->setSenderName(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/name'))
        ->setSenderEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/email'))
        ->setTemplateSubject('Prova di Ordine Confermato dopo pagamento');
    $result = $emailTemplate->send(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email'),(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name'), $observer->getCustomer()->getData());

    /*
         - build data
         - build email structure
         - send email via any php mailer method you want
    */
    return $this;  // always return $this.
}
}
```

Can you pls help me to undestand why the error for a comma? Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

There in magento has two dispatch event 
1.sales_order_payment_place_end
2. sales_order_payment_place_start.
As per your Please follow my below code. add observer

```
<global>
        <events>
            <sales_order_payment_place_end>
                <observers>
                    <mymodule>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>mymodule/observer</class>
                        <method>handleOrder</method>
                    </mymodule>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_payment_place_end>           
        </events>
    </global>
```

Then create observer.php under model directory

```
class Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Observer
{   
    public function handlePayment($observer)
    {
       $order = $observer->getOrder();
       $payment=$order->getPayment();
       /// put logic as per your requirement.
    }
}
```

I did not get time to test this code but i am sure logic is same like this. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i've edited the principal post with the code used. I've One error for a comma.